# Open URLs with given string | strip one character from string on each URL run

Tags: batch-file

Created batch file:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set execute counter=0
Set "Pass=45454545854545854254545454"
Echo Password is:%Pass%
start "" https://xxx.xxx/xxx/%pass%
:test
set "Pass=%Pass%"
set "Pass=!Pass:~1,-1!
echo Password is :%Pass%
start "" https://xxx.xxx/xxx/%pass%
goto test
```

**Requirements**: I want to open URL with given `%pass%` string, on each loop I want to strip the last character from string until one character will remain for URL.

Example:

```
1st url : https://xxx.xxx/xxx/45454545854545854254545454
2nd url : https://xxx.xxx/xxx/4545454585454585425454545
.......
last url : https://xxx.xxx/xxx/4
```

Comment: `set "Pass=%Pass%"` is useless. Also, `set "Pass=!Pass:~1,-1!` will remove **first and last number/character**.

Comment: A typo: `echo` instead of `eacho`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```abt
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "execute counter=0"
Set "Pass=45454545854545854254545454"
Echo Password is: %Pass%
start "" https://xxx.xxx/xxx/%pass%
goto test

:test
set "Pass=!Pass:~0,-1!"
if defined Pass (
   echo Password is: !Pass!
   start "" https://xxx.xxx/xxx/!pass!
   rem pause
   rem Add pause not to overload your computer!
   goto test
) else (
   echo No more characters to strip!
   pause
   exit /b
)
```

I have quoted `execute counter` variable in `set` to avoid any strange behaviours. Added a `goto test` after the end of main code (not really needed).

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with much less code.

```
@echo off
Set "Pass=45454545854545854254545454"
:loop
echo https://xxx.xxx/xxx/%pass%
set "pass=%pass:~0,-1%"
IF DEFINED pass GOTO loop
```